# Update the Map field - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to update data of isVerified (Boolean) field.
Personal Info is Map contains address and then isVerified.

[image]

Comment: little help from my side @JesusLovesYou for upvoates of inscrease, did you get it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To update `isVerified`, you have to do the following:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("collection Name").document("documentId").updateData({
    "Personal Info.address.isVerified": true,
  }).then((_) {
    print("success!");
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not provide your collection or document name I would just form one

So lets assume every time we click a button the value should be changed to true

```
CollectionReference humanCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("collection Name");
//This is the button
FlatButton(
onPressed: () => changeValue();
 child : Container(
   Text : 'Change Value'
)
),

//This is the function

changeValue(){

humanCollection
        .document(currentHuman.id)//put the document name here
        .updateData({
          'Personal Info.address.isVerified' : true,
         });
}
```

Comment: 'true' will update it as a string but it has to be updated as a Boolean so only true will work

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy use below line where ever you want to update data in firebase.

**.** is used to access key of sub-map.

```
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection Name').doc('documentId').update({'Personal Info.address.isVerified' : true,});
```

version : cloud_firestore: 3.1.11