# Flutter - Update values of maps and arrays in Cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have my Cloud Firestore database as follows

[image]

Here `Education` is a map and `Skills` is array. I have couple more arrays and maps. How can I edit these values with flutter.

I was guessing maybe like

```
return Firestore.instance.collection('data/users/$uid')
        .document('user_data')
        .updateData({
      "Education[High school]" : _highSchool,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

didn't test it but maybe this will work

```
return Firestore.instance.collection('data/users/$uid')
        .document('user_data')
        .setData({
      "Education.High school" : _highSchool,
    });
  }
```

also there is similar question like that check it out
[Update the Map field - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214831/update-the-map-field-flutter)